# Spark SQL "No input paths specified in jobs" when create DataFrame based on JSON file

Tags: python, json

I am a beginner in Spark and I am trying to create a DataFrame based on the content of JSON file using PySpark by following the guide: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/sql-programming-guide.html#overview

However, whenever I execute this command (using both relative path or absolute path)

```
df = sqlContext.read.json("examples/src/main/resources/people.json")
```

always gives me the error

```
java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job
```

[Snapshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l7Vn.png)

What is the cause of these issue or is there any Spark configuration that I have missed out? I am using Spark 1.6.1 and Python 2.7.6.

Comment: what are you doing here I mean using local mode or yarn mode ??

Answer (score 3):

I run into this problem too, add "file://" or "hdfs://" works for me! Thanks for Jessika's answer!!!

In conclusion, if your json file is in your local file system,use

```
df = sqlContext.read.json("file:///user/ABC/examples/src/main/resources/people.json")
```

else, if your json file is in hdfs, use

```
df = sqlContext.read.json("hdfs://ip:port/user/ABC/examples/src/main/resources/people.json")
```

Comment: I was using file:// in front of the file location and it prompts:
File file:/home/ABC/data/airports-extended.dat does not exist
After I removed file:// from the location, it seems to be able to find the file; However, when I do df.show(10), I am still getting error:
No input paths specified in job

Answer (score 2):

try to add file:// at the beginning of your absolute path:
df = sqlContext.read.json("file:///user/ABC/examples/src/main/resources/people.json")

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your code on local mode then provide complete path of your file.
Suppose your file location is "/user/ABC/examples/src/main/resources/people.json". Then your code should be like this.

```
df =sqlContext.read.json("/user/ABC/examples/src/main/resources/people.json")
```

If you are running your code yarn mode then check your file exist in HDFS and provide complete location

```
df = sqlContext.read.json("/user/ABC/examples/src/main/resources/people.json")
```

Comment: I am runnig on yarn-client mode. I have copy people.json to HDFS by doing the following:
    `hadoop fs -mkdir /user/hadoop/dir1`
    `hadoop fs -put people.json /user/hadoop/dir1/people.json`
But it still show the same error. Did I missed out anything?

Comment: Then your  code should be **df = sqlContext.read.json("/user/hadoop/dir1/people.json")** and it should work

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the file system protocol:

- **hdfs** Hadoop File System (used by default)
- **file** local file system
- **s3a** / **s3n** AWS S3
- **swift**

But also, the path must exist where the Spark driver and worker(s) are executed.