# Spark error in reading file - Exception in thread “main” java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark, Hadoop & Scala. I have a situation where I need to read from a local directory/file from Scala/Spark, and I am facing issues. I see others have come across the same issue, but I don't see a solution though.

I am using Spark 1.6.2

My code reads like this:

```
def main(arg: Array[String]): Unit = {

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyAppName").setMaster("local[*]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

val resultDf = sqlContext.read.json("/opt/app/poc/myfile.json")
}
```

I am getting the following error: `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job`

**Note:** My application is installed and running in `/opt/app/spark` and I am calling it by calling `/usr/bin/spark-submit --class com.mycom.TestMyApp /opt/app/spark/App.jar`. I cannot move the json file inside the project jar file - the necessity is to read it from local directory.

I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong. Please help.

Here is part of the stacktrace:

```
>Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job
>>        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:202)
>>        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
>>        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)
>>        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242)
>>        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240)
>>        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
>>        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240)
>>        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>> ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark SQL "No input paths specified in jobs" when create DataFrame based on JSON file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38150311/spark-sql-no-input-paths-specified-in-jobs-when-create-dataframe-based-on-json)

Comment: are u running your application just locally or in a cluster of machines?

Comment: append this `file://` in starting of url